# Eliminacion de registros Hijos si no existe el registro padre

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

tengo este problema: tengo tabla1[padre] y tabla2[hijos], entonces se eliminaron unos registros padres y no se le coloco delete on cascade, ahora no se como eliminar los registros hijos cuando no tiene registro padre. Esto es una app hecha con laravel,les agradeceria la ayuda o aportacion de posible solucion, Gracias de ante mano.

Comment: ¿qué has investigado o intentado?

Comment: ve lo q tengo en mente, buscar de la tabla hijos y verificar si existe el id en la tabla padre, si no existe me lo elimine.. pero no me da la cuestion como para hacerlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE h FROM hijo h LEFT JOIN padre p ON p.id = h.id_padre WHERE p.id IS NULL;
```

Esto eliminará cualquier registro hijo donde no encuentre un registro padre.

Comment: Eres un crack!. ya la use con un select y me funciono, ahora vere como la corro directamente por sql